# How to copy lines above the cursor?

Tags: vim, copy

It is sample text file here,the cursor located on 4th line.

[image]

To input 2yy in the current status--normal mode,

```
test4
test5
```

The above two lines ,which below the cursor copied.
How to copy two lines above the cursor instead of below?

```
test3
test4
```

To input 1k and 2yy can get it,is there another way?
Both  -2yy and 2YY  can't work.

Comment: I would have done `v2ky`

Comment: ```y1k``` seems to work well

Comment: I can only think of an approximation, which maybe will help other people to think of a solution. When defining `:map Y HV''y`>` you could input `3Y` to copy from the third line shown on the screen to the end of the cursor's line. I wonder if there's also a way to create a mapping which will allow a count of the number of lines to copy above and will jump back to the correct line and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vky` works, just because it is in line block mode. `y1k` works, but the logic behind `Vky` seems more straightforward to me.

Answer (score 2):

The key combinations mentioned in the comments work. If you want to, you can also add the following mapping to your startup options and then use `2Y` to copy the current line and the line above without moving the cursor.

```
function! CopyLinesAbove(count)
  cal setreg('"',join(getline(line('.') - a:count + 1,line('.') + 1),"\n")."\n")
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 CopyLinesAboveCmd call CopyLinesAbove(<args>)
map Y :<C-U>CopyLinesAboveCmd(v:count)<CR>
```